# TypeScript generics and function parameter conditional types

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Let's say I have a function that returns the return value of a passed-in `getIdentifier` function. This function is mandatory, except for when the `item` has an `id` property because I can fall back to reading just that.

```js
type FuncArg<T> = T extends { id: string }
  ? { item: T; getIdentifier?: (item: T) => string }
  : { item: T; getIdentifier: (item: T) => string };

type withId<T> = T & { id: string };

const getFoobar = <T>(arg: FuncArg<T>) => {
  return arg.getIdentifier ? arg.getIdentifier(arg.item) : (arg.item as withId<T>).id;
};
```

All well so far. Let's say I have a second function that passes in an item to the first function, checks if it has an `id` and if not it passes in a random generator `getIdentifier`.

```js
const getFoobar2 = <T>(item: T) => {
  if ('id' in item) return getFoobar({item: item as withId<T>});
  return getFoobar({item: item, getIdentifier: () => Math.random().toString()});
}
```

Unfortunately the typechecking breaks in the last example and I have no idea to fix this. I've tried everything from conditional types to union types and function overloads. Everytime I run into similar problems. What am I missing here?

[Playground ▶](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgrgOwMYEEBOBzAPAFQHxQC8UOUEAHsBAgCYDOUA3lAJY0BcUdwaLCGUAL4BYAFBQoAfiasqAW044A3FAwRgASRrVgLAGYsIaSZwAULeYoCURAt178hYiZ2YWICkirWbtCXQZGZu6eODaEdjx8AoJKYmKgkFAA7hYAFlq4BMSkAGQybJz20UJxomJIAPYI3KrqMJWVAEYAhmhEUFmmbRic8Mjo2PjhBIzOUGjqcGgIUD0AdD5aOvqG7dILS34Ba92Y8yE2ZgshcwypwBk0WVYHNGWx8aJVNcB1wA3NbQBMHV0h1lsTHG+igpgA5GxwaxZocJlMZu9Pq00KZGADZB4zil0pl8IIrGUJJNgNNZj5kW00RiQgAad7LfyrIJgkZQACyLUu8zQLVolTkpluwEqAGUovwhQSHmIgA)

Answer (score 1):

You missed `item` parameter in `getIdentifier` function signature and looks like it requires explicit  `as FuncArg<T>` in object declaration. Can't explain better, don't have much experience in Typescript.

```
const getFoobar2 = <T>(item: T) => {
  if ('id' in item)
    return getFoobar({ item: item } as FuncArg<T>);
  return getFoobar({item: item, getIdentifier: (item: T) => Math.random().toString()} as FuncArg<T>);
}
```

Comment: That's not it unfortunately. I tried that. If you click on 'Playground ▶' you can play around with the error.

Comment: @Gersom https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgrgOwMYEEBOBzAPAFQHxQC8UOUEAHsBAgCYDOUA3lAJY0BcUdwaLCGUAL4BYAFBQoAfiasqAW044A3FAwRgASRrVgLAGYsIaSZwAULeYoCURAt178hYiZ2YWICkirWbtCXQZGZu6eODaEdjx8AoJKYmKgkFAA7hYAFlq4BMSkAGQybJz20UJxomJIAPYI3KrqMJWVAEYAhmhEUFmmbRic8Mjo2PjhBIzOUGjqcGgIUD0AdD5aOvqG7dILS34Ba92Y8yE2ZgshcwypwBk0WVYHNGWx8aJVNcB1wA3NbQBMHV0h1lsTHG+igpgA5GxwaxZodxhJJsBprMfJ9WmhTG5LLIPEIzrBEKhMDcygipjN3mi2piATi5AAad7LfyrIJg2lhIEAWRal3maBatEqclMt2AlQAylF+KLBPj+kShngrA8gA

Comment: Thanks for having a look with me! Technically this works, but I still feel like there is a gotcha that I'm missing, since it's quite verbose / feels unnecessary.

Comment: This is the right procedure although the answer should maybe be edited to explain what's happening: the compiler cannot usually verify assignability to unspecified generic types, especially *conditional* types that depend on unspecified generic type parameters.  If `T` were some specific type, the compiler could evaluate `FuncArg<T>`, but since it's a generic type parameter, the compiler *defers* evaluating it until later.  So it won't know if `{item: item}`is or is not assignable because it doesn't know what `T` is.  There are github issues about this, let me see if I can find some

Comment: There's [microsoft/TypeScript#36737](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36737) and [microsoft/TypeScript#35257](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/35257) and [microsoft/TypeScript#32990](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32990)...